# bin/rails console doesn't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails & Ruby in general. I was following [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#mvc-and-you-generating-a-model) and got stuck on step 6.3.
my `bin/rails console` result in error below

```
/home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require': cannot load such file -- rdoc (LoadError)
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/lib/irb/input-method.rb:17:in `<main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/lib/irb/context.rb:14:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/lib/irb/context.rb:14:in `<main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/lib/irb.rb:16:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/lib/irb.rb:16:in `<main>'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `block in lookup'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `each'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `lookup'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:73:in `find_by_namespace'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/gaura/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

what I have tried so far

1. googling "can't run rails console" I see some people have similar issue but they have different error
2. I tried to change `gem "bootsnap", require: false` in gemfile to be `gem "bootsnap"` but it still output the same error

**Edit**

As Stefan and ViachMoz pointed out, I seem to be missing "rdoc" gem. The error still exists after I do `gem install rdoc` but adding `gem "rdoc"` to gemfile solves the error. Anyway problem solved, Thank you Stefan and ViachMoz.

Comment: It says _"cannot load such file -- rdoc"_ – try `gem install rdoc`

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` first?  If `doc` is required, it should be in the `Gemfile.rb` or as a dependency on the `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: This isn't mentioned in the official tutorial of rails. It should get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `gem install rdoc`. Basically you're missing a gem.